# Travel from Britain to EU for third-country nationals

Tags: customs-and-immigration, schengen, paperwork, covid-19

British nationals can certainly travel to the European Union, even without being required to quarantine. But if a national of a country that is not on the list of allowed third countries travelers have been in Britain long-term under a long-duration tourist visa or visa-exempt passport, but without a residence permit, will they be denied entry to the EU? Or will they be admitted? Would there be certain documents that they would be expected to provide?

Comment: There are **two** simple **yes/no** questions that need to be answered: 1) Do you fullfill the immigration conditions to enter the Schengen Area? 2) Have you been, in the last 14 days, in a low-risk country with comparable health and safety measures as the EU?  If both answers are **yes** then you may enter, otherwise you may not. At present, nobody can make head or tails as to to whether 1) can be answered with **yes** based on the information you have supplied.

Comment: By the immigration conditions, I assume you mean the usual ones to enter the European Union in the absence of pandemic restrictions? Also I thought the specific number of 14 days was a US law thing. It does not seem to be mentioned in the EU documents that I have seen, thus my question.

Comment: Yes, now that nonessential travel is again allowed they have generally reverted back to the way they were. 14 days is generally assumed as the period where first symptoms become noticeable.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on the EU country. As you can see on https://reopen.europa.eu/en and https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news/1580226297.htm, each EU country has a different policy. For example, from my understanding of the current policies, as a someone who has been in Britain long-term under a long-duration tourist visa or visa-exempt passport, but without a residency permit in the UK, can travel to Croatia as a tourist (see IATA "passengers traveling as tourists with a confirmation of accommodation booking") and France regardless of your intent (see https://reopen.europa.eu/en/map/FRA: "voluntary quarantine for travellers from the UK."; no need to be a tourist).

Comment: The two sites seem to disagree, because one talks about residency and the other talks about travellers coming from a country.

Comment: @Obie2.0 yes it's sometimes contradictory. IATA only states rules for air travel by the way I believe. 
 https://reopen.europa.eu/en has rules for air and non-air-travel. So make sure you compare the rules addressing the same travel medium.

Comment: When would a traveller be rejected? At the airport or by passport control?

Comment: @Obie2.0 I'm not sure in the case of Europe. Check-in front desk is probably the first step where you may get rejected, typically based on IATA information.

Comment: @Obie2.0 The rules vary from country to country. Many impose no restrictions when arriving from the UK or an EU/Schengen state. Where are you looking to travel?

Comment: I am thinking about the requirements in Spain in particular.

Comment: @Obie2.0 FYI  [Do airlines still use the same info as on the IATA website during the COVID-19 pandemic, or do they have access to more up-to-date, exhaustive info?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/158280/1810) What a mess. Good way to restart the travel industry.

Comment: What about trains? Are they any different?

Comment: @Obie2.0 unsure, I haven't used them this year to cross borders and don't plan to soon (in my current country and neighbors, borders are mostly closed for both train and plane). If I go to Europe I'd fly into it, so I didn't pay attention to trains.

Answer (score 0):

Per TIMATIC, you can enter Spain in the following cases:

- If arriving from EU/Schengen/UK
- If residing in EU/Schengen/UK, Andorra, Australia, Canada, Georgia, Japan, Monaco, Montenegro, New Zealand, Rwanda, San Marino, Serbia, Thailand, Tunisia, Uruguay or the Vatican
- If holding a Schengen D visa
- If eligible to hold an Article 10/20 family member residence card